# Failover Cluster Disk Replication

Tags: windows, cluster, replication, failovercluster, cluster-shared-volumes

We have a Windows failover cluster containing a shared disk assigned to a Role and want to set up replication from it.

We tried removing the disk from the cluster to use DFS Replication,  however we lose access to the network shares of the disk even once they are recreated with the same permissions and pathways. We regained access once we recreated the role with the shared disk.

Going off of that, we need to replicate within the cluster. When configuring storage replication, our second shared disk that is in available storage is ineligible due to the flag "Not in a different site."

I'm unable to find anything related to this error, and the Windows guides I have found all show Cluster to Cluster replication.

Could anyone explain this flag or does anyone know of the proper way to configure the cluster storage replication?

Comment: Replace DFS-R file-level replication with a block-level replication. It's way more reliable, faster (doesn't read after initial write), and can deal with open files. DFS-R cannot...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Storage replica supports either Cluster-To-Cluster replication or Stretch Cluster with shared storage. Technically you should be able to configure it, if you have separate shared storage connected to your cluster nodes.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/storage-replica/storage-replica-frequently-asked-questions

As for DFS-R, you might need to configure shares on a different server and then migrate data. Replication can be configured afterwards.

As another option, Starwinds VSAN can be used to handle replication and present shared storage to Failover Cluster. The following guide covers the configuration: https://www.starwindsoftware.com/resource-library/starwind-virtual-san-for-hyper-v-2-node-hyperconverged-scenario-with-windows-server-2016/

Comment: Thank you for the response, we had been on a shorter time frame to get a solution in place so we had used a batch job and a scheduled task which has been working surprisingly well while also allowing us to utilize a Veeam backup and replication solution.